# How to input vertices information in the polygon function in R?

Tags: r, plot, polygon, xts, posixct

I have an xts object called "y". What I am trying to do is, create transparent gray-shaded rectangles on an existing plot. [Please see this attached picture, for example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5vma.jpg)  To produce the rectangle in the attached plot, I have written the following codes:

```
temp.x = attr(y, 'index')
class(temp.x) = c('POSIXct', 'POSIXt')

#Plotting the time-series "y"
plot(temp.x, y, type = 'l', xaxt = 'n')

#The following function plots the rectangle on the plot just created above
polygon(c(temp.x[103],temp.x[103],temp.x[111],temp.x[111]),c(plot_range[4],plot_range[3],plot_range[3],plot_range[4]), col=adjustcolor("gray", alpha=0.5), border=NA)

#The following codes are written to display all the years in the x-axis  
r <- as.POSIXct(round(range(temp.x), "hours"))
range(temp.x)
axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(r[1], r[2], by = "year"), format="%Y")
```

Now, here is my question: Instead of providing the index numbers for e.g. temp.x[103] or temp.x[111] to the polygon function, is there any way I could just provide the specific dates as an x-axis coordinate? For example, my inputs in the polygon function are such that the rectangle starts at 1990-07-01 and ends at 1991-03-01. Could you please suggest me a way so that instead of writing temp.x[103], I could just write "1990-07-01" as an input argument for the polygon function?

Thank you so much for your patience. Your help will be highly appreciated. If something I said is not clear, please let me know.

Comment: For example, just pass `as.POSIXct("1990-07-01")` for July 1 as an argument to `polygon()` It should get converted to the correct numerical point on your graph.

Comment: @thelatemail Can't thank you enough! You solved a big problem which I couldn't fix despite trying the last few days.